# Writing a dictionary to a csv file in python 2.7

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to write a dictionary that looks like this:
{'2234': '1', '233': '60'}
into a new csv file that has been created.
I found a page where this was answered and I tried this out in python 2.7  but this still gives me an error whilst executing my code:

```
with open('variabelen.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)  
    for name, items in a.items():    
        writer.writerow([name] + items)
```

When i execute the code this shows up for me as an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Danny/Desktop/Inventaris.py", line 48, in <module>
    Toevoeging_methode_plus(toevoegproduct, aantaltoevoeging)
  File "/Users/Danny/Desktop/Inventaris.py", line 9, in Toevoeging_methode_plus
    writecolumbs()
  File "/Users/Danny/Desktop/Inventaris.py", line 24, in writecolumbs
    writer.writerow([name] + items)
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are concatenating a list `[name]` with a string `items` - hence the error.

Instead, you can simply write `items()` via [`.writerows()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows):

```
with open('variabelen.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(a.items())
```

Given the value of `a = {'2234': '1', '233': '60'}`, it would produce `variabelen.csv` with the following content:

```
233,60
2234,1
```

The order of rows though may differ cause dictionaries in Python are *unordered collections*.

Comment: Is it possible to take a transpose of this with the same method? for example; have 233 and 2234 as column names and collect their values under those names? Thank you! @alecxe